# Deleting multiple files from git

Tags: git

Other than individually deleting each file (i.e. `git rm src/classes/Config.php`, `git rm src/public/ajax.php`, etc, etc), how can all these files be deleted from git?

```
[Michael@devserver main]$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    src/classes/Config.php
#       deleted:    src/public/ajax.php
#       deleted:    src/public/fileuploader.php
#       deleted:    src/public/index2.php
#       deleted:    src/public/json_encode.php
#       deleted:    src/public/petstore.json
#       deleted:    src/public/resources/index.php
#       deleted:    src/public/slimttest.php
#       deleted:    src/public/temp.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test/bla.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test/file1.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test/file2.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test2.php
#       deleted:    src/public/testAPI.php
#       deleted:    src/public/testAPI2.php
#       deleted:    src/public/test_original.php
#       deleted:    src/public/testfile.php
#       deleted:    temporary.txt
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
[Michael@devserver main]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git add --update` or `git add -u` in short to stage all changes that are displayed in the *“Changed but not updated”* section in `git status`.

Using this option on [`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) will *not* stage untracked files, so it’s safe to use even when you have lots of other changes (unlike `git add -A`).

This is especially helpful for situations like yours where you have lots of removed files. If you have some changes you do not want to stage, you can afterwards use `git reset <path>` to unstage the change (without undoing that change of course).

Comment: What if I already added them using `git add .`?  Maybe do `git checkout -- *`, and then do as you say?

Comment: `git add .` will only add files it physically finds in the working directory. So you will not be able to stage file removals that way. And using `git add -u` will not affect your already staged changes; it works *additionally*, so whatever you staged stays staged but *in addition* all changes in the *“Changed but not updated”* section are also added.

Comment: Didn't attempt to check them out, but just did `git add -u`, and all is good.

Comment: `git checkout -- *` will actually *undo* all unstaged changes in the current directory. So you should not do that if you want to keep your changes :)

Comment: @poke Except it doesn't undo deletions, because * is interpreted by the shell, and the shell doesn't know about the deleted files.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `git add -u` (or `--update`). From `man git add`:

> This removes as well as modifies index entries to match
>   the working tree, but adds no new files.